# PHP script runs "every minute" but not at specified times

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron job for root as follows:

`0 12 * * * /bin/bash /var/www/tools/ebs-volume-snapshots.sh`

This job does not run nor does /var/log/cron give any indication that it has attempted to run the job.  It will run every minute if I enter it as follows:

`* * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/tools/ebs-volume-snapshots.sh`

It will also run every two minutes (*/2).

I am at a loss!  This snapshots script freezes two XFS filesystems and creates an EBS snapshot on the Amazon cloud (then unfreezes the filesystems) and the command works perfectly fine from the shell prompt, every time.

The OS is CentOS 5.6 on an EC2 server.  The only other cron job in root's crontab runs every 10 minutes successfully.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions!
-bobby

Comment: Was the machine powered on at 12:00? Sorry for the simple question, but it's always best to start at the beginning without assumptions.

Comment: How often / what time are you trying to set it up to run?

Comment: @ChrisHenry Looks like he's trying to run it at noon every day.

Comment: if im not mistaken 0 12 * * * means it would only run once a day at 12

Comment: Another follow-on to @lc 's question: Is the EC2 instance's clock synchronized with your local time? If you expect it to run at 12 local time but the server is set to run at 12Z, then that could be part of the issue as well.